# Short clarification on induction prove with Gamma defnition

Tags: proof-verification

Suppose we are asked to prove this one using induction:

$$k! = \int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k} dx \,\,\, (*)$$

For $k=0$, it is clear after evaluating the appropriate improper integral that,

$$0! = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = 1$$

For the induction case, is it possible just to do this?

Assuming $(*)$ holds now, we just multiply everything by $(k+1)$ to both sides so that we get,

$$k!(k+1) = k\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k} dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k} dx = (k+1)!$$

Therefore by induction, $(*)$ is true for all natural number with zero included. Do we need to even do integration by part here? I thought it is only needed if we want to specifically prove the special recursive relation of Gamma function.

Further steps:

\begin{align}k!(k+1) &= (k+1)! = (k+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k} dx \\ 
&= -e^{-x}x^{k+1}\Big|_0^{\infty} + (k+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k} dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, do use integration by parts.

Comment: If you would mind, my question is why do we need to do that if we already assume $(*)$ is true as part of the inductive step? Can't we just multiply $(*)$ with $(k+1)$ to imply that $k+1$ case holds.

Comment: It's not entirely clear without doing integration by parts that the term you have in the middle of your inductive step is the same as $\int _0 ^\infty e^{-x}t^{k+1}dx$, which is what you need to show

Comment: ok I just added further steps, is it ok now?

Comment: You should reorganize the i.b.p. argument; as written it looks like you prove that $k!(k + 1) = (k + 1)!$, which is essentially the definition of the factorial.

Comment: So you used integration by parts. It would be much clearer (and more likely to be graded as correct) if you started with $\int_0^\infty x^{k+1}e^{-x}\,dx$, let $u=x^{k+1}$ and $dv=e^{-x}\,dx$, then went through the integration by parts concluding the result is $(k+1)\int_0^\infty x^ke^{-x}\,dx$, and then used the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Ok with that procedure in mind, will it look like this? We start with $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k+1}$ and after doing the intermediate step as well as invoking induction hypothesis, we conclude that it is equal to $(k+1)!$ Is it also okay if I start with what I have added in my question, then ends in integral only? (So that I don't imply the definition of factorial) *edited the first post*

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your amended answer,
I see that it is correct,
but I am 
a little bothered by your exposition.
That is probably my problem.

When doing integration by parts,
I find it helpful to explicitly state
the parts.
I also
first do it as an
indefinite integral
and then assign the limits.

From first principles,
$(uv)'
=uv'+u'v
$,
so
$uv
=\int uv' + \int u'v
$
or
$\int uv'
= uv - \int u'v
$.

In this case,
$uv'
=e^{-x}x^{k}dx
$.
If we choose
$u = e^{-x}$
and
$v' = x^k dx$,
then
$u' = -e^{-x}dx$
and
$v = \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$,
so the result is
$\int e^{-x}x^{k}dx
=e^{-x}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}-\int (-e^{-x})\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}dx
$
or
$\int e^{-x}x^{k+1}dx
=(k+1)\int e^{-x}x^{k}dx-e^{-x}x^{k+1}
$.

At this point,
when we assign the limits
$0$ to $\infty$,
we get your results
in the form
$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{k+1}dx
=(k+1)\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{k}dx-e^{-x}x^{k+1}\big|_0^{\infty}
=(k+1)\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{k}dx
$.

Comment: Now I'm confused, it is ordinary integration by part right? Why are they suddenly not equal? $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k+1} =
 -e^{-x}x^{k+1}\Big|_0^{\infty} + (k+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k} dx
$ Then the first term will vanish as the upper terminal approaches infinity.

Comment: You should go the other way: start with $\int e^{-x}x^{k+1}dx$, integrate this by parts, and get the expression involving $\int e^{-x}x^{k}dx$.

Comment: Ok but this is equal right? $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k+1}= -e^{-x}x^{k+1}\Big|_0^{\infty} + (k+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{k} dx$
  Is it because the calculation involves improper integral you cannot simply switch the expression in the equality? Can you elaborate what do you mean that it is not equal?

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer. I think I would have liked a few more steps in yours written out, but I now think it was correct.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your explanation.